# Add image for Slider thumb in xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I would like to add image for thumb of xaml slider control in windows store app,
How to add,is it possible in windows store app?

Answer (score 2):

You have to customize the thumb.

[Slider styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj709929.aspx)

Default style

```
<!-- Default style for Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Slider -->
<Style TargetType="Slider">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource SliderBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="ManipulationMode" Value="None" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Slider">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                    <Grid.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Thumb" x:Key="SliderThumbStyle">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBorderThemeBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </Grid.Resources>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPressedBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalBorder"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalBorder"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderDisabledBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreaseDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="TopTickBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BottomTickBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LeftTickBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RightTickBar"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkOutsideDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackDecreasePointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalTrackRect"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderTrackPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalThumb"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SliderThumbPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhiteVertical"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlackVertical"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="HorizontalTemplate" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="17" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalTrackRect"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalDecreaseRect"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Grid.Row="1" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="TopTickBar"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                 Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                 Margin="0,0,0,2"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="HorizontalInlineTickBar"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                 Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                 Grid.Row="1"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTickBar"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                 Height="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                 Margin="0,2,0,0"
                                 Grid.Row="2"
                                 Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="HorizontalBorder"
                                   Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                   StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                   Grid.Row="1"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="HorizontalThumb"
                               Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                               Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                               DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                               Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                               Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteHorizontal"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                   StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackHorizontal"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                   StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid x:Name="VerticalTemplate" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalTrackRect"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalDecreaseRect"
                                   Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.Row="2" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="LeftTickBar"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                 Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                 Margin="0,0,2,0"
                                 Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="VerticalInlineTickBar"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickMarkInlineBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                 Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                                 Grid.Column="1"
                                 Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <TickBar x:Name="RightTickBar"
                                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                                 Fill="{StaticResource SliderTickmarkOutsideBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                 Width="{StaticResource SliderOutsideTickBarThemeHeight}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                 Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                 Grid.Column="2"
                                 Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="VerticalBorder"
                                   Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                   StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"                                
                                   Grid.Column="1"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="3" />
                        <Thumb x:Name="VerticalThumb"
                               Background="{StaticResource SliderThumbBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                               Style="{StaticResource SliderThumbStyle}"
                               DataContext="{TemplateBinding Value}"
                               Width="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                               Height="{StaticResource SliderTrackThemeHeight}"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhiteVertical"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                   StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   StrokeDashOffset="1.5"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                        <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlackVertical"
                                   IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                   Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                   StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                   StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                   Opacity="0"
                                   StrokeDashOffset="0.5"
                                   Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```